# How to set margin between columns with width 33%?

Tags: html, css

I think it was a lot of similar questions but I have not found a good solution. I have a container which contain 3 columns with width 33%. I want to add margin between them like as screenshot. 
[image]

I try so:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.column {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.column:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

but the last column moves to a new line. How to add a space between blocks without changing the width?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabric/cwvutzgb/)

Comment: Maximum width is 100%, and your are using 1/3rd of it for each column. Then how can you use margin? You should reduce width of columns

Comment: make `width: 30.33%;` in .column class

Comment: @niyasc, Yes I know, I try set padding but I need to first column was pinned to the left side, and the last to the right. All columns must have the same width.

Comment: Could using flexbox help here?

Comment: See example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0w777rv/)

Comment: @towerofnix, I thought about it, but I need cross browser solution

Comment: @JagdishParmar, I need margin in `px`

Comment: Looks to me like flexbox is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) on most browsers, except for some old versions of IE.

Comment: can you modify your html? if yes then you can use this method [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwvutzgb/4/) `bootstrap strategy`

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes, I think this is a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, the width of the columns must be less that 33% of the container since you are adding 20px margin in some instances. *Unless 40px is exactly equal to 1% of the width, of course.*

I suspect what you are after is the columns are of equal size *after* the margins are added...so 33% of the remaining width.

**Flexbox** can do that.

[**Flexbox Support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is IE10 and up

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
}
.column {
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.column:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

**Calc Solution**

[**Calc Support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) is IE9 and up

As mentioned in other answers, `calc` can be used to define the width of the columns taking into account the required margins.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc((100%-40px)/3);
}
.column:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) method on column's width:

```
.column{
   width: calc(33.33% - 20px);
   /* ------------------^^define margin vlaue*/
}
```

Before using calc method have a look in [can i use calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

---

But really, if I were coding, I wouldn't use it because I would simply decrease the width from 33.33% to something like 30%.

Answer (score 0):

buddy.. your 20% is not gonna work, coz it doesn't sums to 100%.! 
Still, if you want some equal margin, this is what you can get.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.column {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.column+.column {
margin-left:0.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, now as we want 3 equal columns arrange properly. so use 30.5% instead of 33% because of padding that will acquire rest of the space.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px ;
}

.column {
    width: 30.5%;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.column:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column">Column 2</div>
    <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an inner div into each column in order to control margins:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    width: 500px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}

.column {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .column__inner {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 200px;
  }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column__inner">Column 1</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column__inner">Column 1</div>  
    </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="column__inner">Column 1</div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```